# Hello World before original bootloader

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I am trying to write a "Hello World" before my bootloader starts.

I know how to run Hello World before start, but I have no idea, how to start the original bootloader after mine is done.

I am using Linux - Minix, and I am adding my assembly code like this:

> dd if=my_bootloader of=/dev/c0d0 bs=512 count=1

where, my_bootloader is an assembly code compiled by nasm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Load it from disk then jump to it?

Comment: @Jester Could you elaborate more on this? How can I know where the old bootloader is stored then?

Comment: It's stored nowhere, you have just overwritten it. You will need to store it somewhere and load it.

Comment: I thought that maybe it is possible to move the old bootloader, and insert "Hello world" before it. Could you give some tips how can I do it? Or some helpful links? Because I was trying to google some tutorials and I unfortunately have found nothing.

Comment: Depending on your disk structure, you may be able to copy the old bootloader into the second sector.

Comment: You sure this is Linux?